# laravel sail getting started

Tags: php, laravel, wsl-2

I'm on Windows with WSL2, I did what the tutorial says https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows, and the installation completed with errors and the `example-app` folder didn't get created.

```bash
~$ curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
latest: Pulling from laravelsail/php82-composer
bb263680fed1: Pull complete
0825793cba86: Pull complete
de3c011d207b: Pull complete
7e3c5bd9650e: Pull complete
e5ef4f07283b: Pull complete
729644263cfa: Pull complete
9c646fe3f3c5: Pull complete
e7c9e0a2bc78: Pull complete
87fd6a1f6441: Pull complete
136b5bfaa68e: Pull complete
cf33f30cc64a: Pull complete
9250c2dfc674: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
59bc22386503: Pull complete
376a1c60a489: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:37549f980be6146efcb16b0dc352644edfc5cca32b9862494631eb197ef89737
Status: Downloaded newer image for laravelsail/php82-composer:latest

   _                               _
  | |                             | |
  | |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
  | |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
  | |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
  |______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|

   WARN  TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.

    Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./example-app"
    https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to repo.packagist.org:443 ), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

    In CurlDownloader.php line 365:

  curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/laravel/larav
  el.json: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to repo.packa
  gist.org:443


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]

bash: line 17: cd: example-app: No such file or directory
bash: line 19: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory
bash: line 20: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory

Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.

[sudo] password for my-user:

Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

after this, no folder exists with `example-app`

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: @AlexHowansky what do this question and that one have in common? I don't get it

Comment: It's the same error message `curl error 35 while downloading...`

Comment: @AlexHowansky you are right! Thanks! I found the way to install this. I merely run the line: `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` as mentioned in other answers, like the one you mentioned. I'll close this out